# Отключается ввод с клавиатуры при работе в Android Studio на Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, android-studio, intellij-idea

Когда я работаю в Android Studio, загадочным образом клавиатура перестает реагировать на ввод. Я подозреваю, что я случайно могу нажимать на комбинацию каких-то клавиш, которые просто выключают клавиатуру. Так как в целом в других приложениях все нормально работает, а в студии - нет. Приходиться закрывать студио и открывать снова. Кто сталкивался с такой проблемой и нашел решение?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть соответствующая [заявка](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-78860) на баг-трекере *Intellij*.
Варианты решения:

1. Перезапустить службу *IBus* из консоли: `ibus-daemon -rd`.
2. Обновить *IBus* до последней версии (IDE при старте должна выводить предупреждение, возможно, вы его просто проигнорировали).
3. Отключить *IBus* полностью `System Settings | Language Support | Keyboard input method`.
4. Добавить `export XMODIFIERS=""` в `idea.sh` (либо соответствующий скрипт запуска среды разработки).

Comment: А если я выберу 3-й вариант, чтоб больше не заморачиваться, это не повредит остальным настройкам и прочее?

Comment: Остальным настройкам не повредит, но не сможете вводить всякие иероглифы. Попробуйте отключить и если все устраивает, то оставляйте. Либо просто обновите IBus.

Comment: Я работаю в приложениях с языком ивритом. Ну знаю можно ли это считать иероглифами, но лучше обновлю. А как можно проверить какая версия стоит сейчас , какая доступна и как обновить ее?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/735189/ibus-1-5-11-on-ubuntu

Comment: Я так понял что у него не совсем такая проблема как у меня. Я попробовал выполнить команды, но ниче не получилось

Comment: Как обновить IBus сейчас не смогу подсказать, поскольку нет доступа к Ubuntu. По приведенной ссылке как раз в ответе дан набор команд для обновления, либо поищите сами.